# Java Logger doesn't log to Console

Tags: java, logging

I've a created to following class.

```
package bgu.spl.utils;

import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class AppLogger 
{
    private final static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger("MyAppLogger");
    private static boolean _isInited = false;

    private synchronized static void init()
    {
        _logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        _logger.addHandler(handler);

        _isInited = true;
    }

    public synchronized static void general (String text)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        System.out.println(text);
    }

    private static String tickStr(int tick)
    {
        return tick < 0 ? "" : (" - Tick: " + tick);
    }

    public synchronized static void severe (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();


        _logger.severe(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }

    public synchronized static void warning (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        _logger.warning(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }

    public synchronized static void info (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        _logger.info(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }

    public synchronized static void config (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        _logger.config(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }

    public synchronized static void fine (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        _logger.fine(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }

    public synchronized static void finer (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        _logger.finer(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }

    public synchronized static void finest (Class<?> type, String text, int tick)
    {
        if (_isInited)
            init();

        _logger.finest(type.getName() + tickStr(tick) + ". " + text);
    }
}
```

my problem is, that nothing is being printed to the console..ive tried mostly to play with the handlers and levels...
of course that the normal `System.out.println` works.
I've created this class to be my entire's multi-threaded app logger.
Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `general`, this

```
if (_isInited)
    init();
```

should be

```
if (!_isInited)
    init();
```

Otherwise it won't call `init()` when `isInited` is `false`. Alternatively, you could use a `static` initialization block like

```
static {
    init(); // <-- will run once.
}
```